# How to get average product rating from laravel model when I used laravel api and react js?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, laravel-api

I have a problem. I am working ecommerce project using laravel api and react js. When I passed products from laravel api, I also want to pass product reviews. I have passed product review list using hasMany join. But I need average review, not review list. Is there any solution like this ? please share with me

Comment: Please provide any relevant code and describe exactly what you're having difficulty with. As it stands your question is vague and open to interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `avg()` class in eloquent

```
Product::find(1)->reviews()->avg('reviews');
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my query. When I return product list using laravel api,, how can access product wise average rating from react js project ?